# Error trying to run Migrate from terminal on Craft 3.4

Tags: migration, plugin-formbuilder2

I am attempting to migrate the content from Form Builder for Craft 2 to Form Builder for Craft 3 by Roundhouse, by using the following command in terminal:
`./craft migrate/up --plugin=roundhouse/form-builder`

However, this is then returning an error telling me my Database credentials are incorrect, despite the fact that I have been and can still access and use the website and its database through every other avenue. The error message given is as follows:

```
Jamess-iMac:multipaneluk jeb$ ./craft migrate/up --plugin=roundhouse/form-builder
Password:
Exception 'craft\errors\DbConnectException' with message 'Craft CMS can’t connect to the database with the credentials in config/db.php.'

in /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/db/Connection.php:171

Stack trace:
#0 /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php(1022): craft\db\Connection->open()
#1 /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php(1009): yii\db\Connection->getMasterPdo()
#2 /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/mysql/QueryBuilder.php(406): yii\db\Connection->getSlavePdo()
#3 /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/mysql/QueryBuilder.php(430): yii\db\mysql\QueryBuilder->supportsFractionalSeconds()
#4 /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/mysql/QueryBuilder.php(59): yii\db\mysql\QueryBuilder->defaultTimeTypeMap()
#5 /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/db/mysql/QueryBuilder.php(27): yii\db\mysql\QueryBuilder->init()
#6 /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php(109): craft\db\mysql\QueryBuilder->init()
#7 /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/QueryBuilder.php(116): yii\base\BaseObject->__construct(Array)
#8 /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/db/mysql/Schema.php(65): yii\db\QueryBuilder->__construct(Object(craft\db\Connection), Array)
#9 /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Schema.php(248): craft\db\mysql\Schema->createQueryBuilder()
#10 /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php(856): yii\db\Schema->getQueryBuilder()
#11 /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Query.php(157): yii\db\Connection->getQueryBuilder()
#12 /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Query.php(302): yii\db\Query->createCommand(Object(craft\db\Connection))
#13 /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/db/Query.php(188): yii\db\Query->scalar(Object(craft\db\Connection))
#14 [internal function]: craft\db\Query->scalar(Object(craft\db\Connection))
#15 /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/caching/DbQueryDependency.php(106): call_user_func(Array, Object(craft\db\Connection))
#16 /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/caching/DbQueryDependency.php(85): yii\caching\DbQueryDependency->executeQuery(Object(craft\db\Query), Object(craft\db\Connection))
#17 /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/caching/Dependency.php(86): yii\caching\DbQueryDependency->generateDependencyData(Object(yii\caching\FileCache))
#18 /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/caching/Cache.php(142): yii\caching\Dependency->isChanged(Object(yii\caching\FileCache))
#19 /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/caching/Cache.php(593): yii\caching\Cache->get('8e0694a5966c89b...')
#20 /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/ProjectConfig.php(1775): yii\caching\Cache->getOrSet('projectConfig:i...', Object(Closure), NULL, Object(yii\caching\DbQueryDependency))
#21 /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/ProjectConfig.php(1625): craft\services\ProjectConfig->_loadInternalConfigData()
#22 /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/ProjectConfig.php(1614): craft\services\ProjectConfig->_getStoredConfig()
#23 /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/ProjectConfig.php(399): craft\services\ProjectConfig->_getLoadedConfig()
#24 /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/base/ApplicationTrait.php(1426): craft\services\ProjectConfig->get('system.timeZone')
#25 /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/base/ApplicationTrait.php(1384): craft\console\Application->_setTimeZone()
#26 /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/console/Application.php(57): craft\console\Application->_preInit()
#27 /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php(109): craft\console\Application->init()
#28 /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(206): yii\base\BaseObject->__construct(Array)
#29 /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/Application.php(89): yii\base\Application->__construct(Array)
#30 /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/console/Application.php(48): yii\console\Application->__construct(Array)
#31 [internal function]: craft\console\Application->__construct(Array)
#32 /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(400): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#33 /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(159): yii\di\Container->build('craft\\console\\A...', Array, Array)
#34 /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(365): yii\di\Container->get('craft\\console\\A...', Array, Array)
#35 /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/bootstrap.php(245): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array)
#36 /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/console.php(43): require('/Users/jeb/Site...')
#37 /Users/jeb/Sites/multipaneluk/craft(21): require('/Users/jeb/Site...')
#38 {main}
```

I've tried using mysql in both Mamp and running through Homebrew, neither of these worked. .env credentials are 100% correct. Can't think what could be causing this.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

We had something similar yesterday. Try the following 2 tweaks:

1.) Delete your storage/runtime folder and then try again

2.) If this does not help, verify the credentials in your .env file and make sure they use a DSN like: `DB_DSN="mysql:host=<dbhost>;port=<dbport>;dbname=<dbname>;"`

Comment: I'm placing a bet on number 1 :) It was a bug and it's now fixed (3.4.19.1)

Comment: Tried both of those, still getting the same issue :(

Comment: sorry no more ideas